# Specifying iOS bundle ID for a trigger.io app

Tags: trigger.io

I have looked through all the documentation, but was unable to find this so I'll ask here...

Right now the bundle ID of my apps once they're loaded on the device io.trigger.forge.  Obviously that won't do for submission to the app store etc because all of my apps, those built with forge and those built otherwise, should start with the same bundle ID.

So, where can I set the bundle ID of the resulting app? Is there a command line argument to the forge tool, or some config.json key?

Answer (score 2):

Doh, I overlooked this:

http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/package_names.html